# PHP not displaying message on empty input

Tags: php, html

This is my PHP and HTML:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
include('db_connect.php');
if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
echo 'Please enter all the required information to proceed';
}
}
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<p></p>
<input type="password" name="pwrd" placeholder="Password">
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Currently when someone leaves one of the text input fields empty, it's meant to display the error 'Please enter all the required information to proceed' - it doesn't seem to be doing that though.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of this conditional statement

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

There is no element bearing the name attribute "submit" for it.

Name your submit input:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In">
```

Error reporting would have thrown something to the effect of

undefined index submit - had it been enabled and to display them or logged.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Having placed an `else{...}` for the first conditional statement, would have echoed "Not set", as per using your existing code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwrd = $_POST['pwrd'];
include('db_connect.php');
if(empty($user) || empty($pwrd)){
echo 'Please enter all the required information to proceed';
}
}

else{ echo "Not set"; }

?>
```

Comment: It seems error reporting didn't display anything though - how do I make it display errors?

Comment: @JugglingBob I've made an edit to my answer for that.

Comment: @JugglingBob question should be marked as solved. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open.